# Group difference or Group Differences

Tags: verb-agreement

I am comparing males with females and young adults (18 to 44 years) and adults (45 to 65 years). I want to say:

1. The group difference based on gender and age is very small.
2. The group differences based on gender and age are very small.

Which of the above is correct?

I am particularly concerned with "difference" versus "differences".

Comment: That would depend on how many differences there are. If there is only one, the use *difference* otherwise use *differences*

Comment: Assuming there was a difference because of gender and a difference because of age, you have *differences.* So I would use your second sentence. (Is the word "group" needed? Could you say, "The differences based on gender and age are very small."?)

Comment: You will have to come back with a more clearly set out question, with background information and context, that is expressed in simple, proper English. It is not clear what the Q. is. Voting to close.

Comment: @Kris - the question is quite clear, using simple words, and proper grammar. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're measuring one variable, use *difference*.  If you're measuring multiple variables, use *differences*.

Comment: Elementary, my dear Watson!